# Displaying videocapture from python to c# web forms

Tags: python, c#, webforms

I have a python file that outputs a live video. I wanted to display the live video in my c# web forms. I tried using IronPython but I think there's something wrong with my code. Is there any way to do this?

This is my python code.

````
def sketch_transform(image):
    image_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return image_grayscale

cam_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
r = (340, 240, 303, 250)
   
while True:   
    _, image_frame = cam_capture.read()
    
    rect_img = image_frame[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]

    border = cv2.rectangle(image_frame, [int(r[0]), int(r[1])], (639, 479), (139,0,0), 1)
    
    sketcher_rect = rect_img
    sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)
    
    #Conversion for 3 channels to put back on original image (streaming)
    sketcher_rect_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(sketcher_rect, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    
    #Replacing the sketched image on Region of Interest
    image_frame[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])] = 
    
    
    cv2.imshow("Sketcher ROI", image_frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        
cam_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```

This is my c# webform code.
````

namespace trial
{
public partial class Form_LiveCam1 : Form
{
public Form_LiveCam1()
{
InitializeComponent();

```
        FilterInfoCollection fic;
        VideoCaptureDevice cam_capture;
        



        fic = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        foreach(FilterInfo dev in fic)
        {
            cam_capture = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            cam_capture = new VideoCaptureDevice(fic[2].MonikerString);
            cam_capture.NewFrame += FinalFrame_NewFrame;
            cam_capture.Start();
        }
    }

    private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        cameraBox.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered re-implementing your python code in C# using a .NET wrapper for OpenCV such as [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) or [Emgu CV](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) ?